# public static final String returns null when accessed

Tags: android

I am puzzled by an instance of a public static final String returning null when referenced.  I've used this exact construct hundreds of times but do not see what I might be doing differently this time.  Code follows:

```
public class NSNItemDisplayActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    public static final String NSN_ID_KEY = "NSN_ID_KEY";
    ...
}
```

Referenced by code that does this:

```
    card.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Intent nsnListIntent = new Intent(
                        mContext,
                        NSNItemDisplayActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = nsnListIntent.getExtras();
                bundle.putString(NSNItemDisplayActivity.NSN_ID_KEY, //Null Pointer Exception
                        card.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(nsnListIntent);
            }
        }
    );
```

I receive a null pointer exception, then sit and scratch my head.

Thank you in advance, I feel silly asking such a simple question.

Comment: I think ur bundle is null not the string. u create an intent and without adding any extras u would get a null bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent nsnListIntent = new Intent(
                        mContext,
                        NSNItemDisplayActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
                bundle.putString(NSNItemDisplayActivity.NSN_ID_KEY, //Null Pointer Exception
                        card.getId());
nsnListIntent.PutExtra("", bundle);
                mContext.startActivity(nsnListIntent);
```

// do this mate

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
bundle.putString(NSNItemDisplayActivity.NSN_ID_KEY
```

won't `return null` unless `bundle` is `null`, from what you are showing us. Initialize your `Bundle` first

```
Intent nsnListIntent = new Intent(mContext, NSNItemDisplayActivity.class);                   
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(NSNItemDisplayActivity.NSN_ID_KEY, card.getId());
```

You don't have any `extras` in your `Intent` to initialize this `Bundle` to since you *just* create it on the previous line.

Maybe you mean to initialize it from the `extras` in an `Intent` used to create this `Activity`. In which case, you would want something like

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```